# generalising a maximisation problem with several constraints with corner solutions

Tags: optimization

Let $U(x,y)$ be a continuous, twice differentiable on its domain: $U_x >0; U_y \ge 0; U_{xx} >0; U_{yy} >0$

The problem is to find $x,y\ge 0$ to maximise $U(x,y)$ subject to $a = x + y + \tau I(y>0)$ where $a, \tau > 0$ are constants; $I(y>0) = 0$ if $y=0$ and $I(y>0) = 1$ if $y>0$.

I solve a simplified problem when $U(x,y) = x(y+1)$ and realise that the solution to the problem can be corner if $a$ is very low or $\tau$ is very high.

But I am not sure how to generalise with the above problem.

Comment: Your function (in the example), $U(x,y)=x(y+1)$, does not satisfy $U_{xx}>0$ nor $U_{yy}>0$ since $U_{xx}=U_{yy}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. I missed the point when I tried. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $U$ is not concave, it's expected that the solution will be a corner one. We consider two auxiliary problems:
\begin{equation}
\max\limits_{\substack{x\\s.t.\\  a-\tau\ge x\ge 0 }} U(x,a-\tau-x) 
\tag{P1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\max\limits_{\substack{x,y\\s.t.\\ a\ge x\ge 0 }} U(x,a-x) 
\tag{P2}
\end{equation}

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the respective solutions of P1 and P2 and $u_1$ and $u_2$ the respective values of the problems. If $x_1<a-\tau$ and $u_1\ge u_2$ then $x_1$ and $y=a-\tau-x_1$ solves the original problem. If $x_2=a$ and $u_2\ge u_1$ then $x_2=a$ and $y=0$ solves the original problem. In all other cases, the original problem does not have a solution.

For example: Take $a=1$ and $\tau=-1$ and $U(x,y)=4x^2+y^2+x+y$. The constraint is $x+y=2$ as long as $y>0$. So, $U$ increases as we increase $x$ and  reduce $y$ but if $y$ hits zero then we are forced to set $x=1$ since the constraint discontinuously changes to $x+y=1$. But $U(2-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)>U(1,0)$ for small $\varepsilon>0$. In sum, we would like to choose $(x,y)=(2,0)$ but due to the discontinuity in the function defining the constraint set, the constraint set is an open. We can approach $(2,0)$ with points in the constraint set but the limit point $(2,0)$ does not satisfy the constraint.

In the new edit version of the question $\tau>0$. In this case, you just need to compare $u_1=\max_{\substack{x\\s.t.\\  a-\tau\ge x\ge 0 }} U(x,a-\tau-x)$ with $U(a,0)$. If the first is greater **and** $a-\tau>x_1$ then the solution of P1 is your answer. If the second is greater then $x=a$ and $y=0$ is your answer. A solution always exist because $U(a-\tau,0)<U(a,0)$ by $U_x>0$.

If $U_{xx}U_{yy}-U_{xy}^2\ge 0$ then your function $U$ is convex. In this case the solution will always be a corner point: the $(x,y)$ that maximizes $U$ subject to your constraint will be either $(a,0)$ or $(0,a-\tau)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very confused with the statement "In all other cases, the original problem does not have a solution." My intuition (using a graph) is that there would always be a solution as the function is continuous and its arguments are bounded (please let me know if I am wrong). So it strikes me to comprehend why it would be the case. 

Can you please refer me to some sources of reading?

Comment: If you know the sign of $\tau$, it is possible to simplify my answer.

Comment: Edited the question to address Thien's comment.

Comment: thank you very much, now I understand that point. I've edited the question to reflect that $\tau >0$ because it seems more intuitive.

Comment: I changed the question to address the fact that now $\tau>0$.

Comment: @Thien: " When people take time to answer your questions, and the answers are helpful to you, it is good to upvote those that are helpful. That's one way to say "thank you" so to speak. Also, for any question you ask, you can "accept" an answer. To upvote, click on the greyed-out up-arrow to the left of the answer. To accept an answer, click on the "greyed-out" check-mark next to the answer you want to accept. That indicates that the answer was particularly helpful/ and/or that it has fully answered your question. "

Comment: Thank you for the introduction. It takes me these two days to understand your answer and now I can fully "accept" the answer. I tried to upvote before as it was particularly useful but because I am having less than 15 reputations, the system does not record my upvote. Thank you for your time and effort.